# Create sequential filename with dd command

Tags: command-line, dd

I'm a bit of a newb when it comes to Linux but I'm trying to restore some files for one of our clients off of an old tape drive. They've requested that we pull the files off in raw 1024k data chunks. The command I'm using to do this is the following:

```
sudo dd /dev/nst0 of=FILE01 bs=1024k
```

This is working just fine, however I'm having to manually change the filename for every file generated and I'm sure there's a better way to do this. Ideally I'd also like to employ the 'sleep' command or something similar so that I don't have to sit and hit enter every few seconds.

Thanks so much guys!!

Answer (score 0):

Use a loop:

```bsh
i=01
while sudo dd if=/dev/nst0 of="FILE$i" bs=1024k count=1 # loop till `dd` errors out
do
    i=$(printf "%02d" $((i+1))) # 0-padded 2-digit number
done
```

Answer (score 0):

One sample solution will be to use `for` loop and `seq` command like this:

```
for i in `seq -f "%02g" 1 99`
do
 sudo dd if=/dev/nst0 of="FILE$i" bs=1024k count=1
done
```